# Overscan under Armbian on a single-board computer (H3-based)

Tags: linux, xorg, arm, framebuffer, armbian

I'm running [Armbian](https://www.armbian.com/) on an [Allwinner H3](http://linux-sunxi.org/H3)-based [SBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer) ([NanoPi M1](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M1)):

[image: NanoPi M1]

As you can see, it has a [CVBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video) out, and fair enough, after a bit of tinkering with the bootloader's [script.bin](http://linux-sunxi.org/Script.bin) (which compiles in and out of an `.ini`-like [FEX format](http://linux-sunxi.org/Fex_Guide) with [bin2fex and fex2bin](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/sunxi-tools/)), and also figuring out the pin order for video on a 3.5mm TRRS jack, I got it talking to one of those old TVs.

But, I was soon reminded of one of the shortcomings of those old TVs: overscan.

[image: tv photo]

This is not even the TV this will be used on, so I can't trust on it having any "auto-fit" option. I'd rather have the framebuffer waste some space on black borders. I'm accessing it via SSH.

I've looked at what boot options the `script.bin` allows, and it does not offer overscan, just setting the resolution. I've also looked at `xrandr`, `fbset` and the files in `/sys/devices/platform/disp/graphics/fb*`, but I can't seem to figure out how overscan can be solved - I only manage to clip the screen to one side. Maybe I have to tell the desktop environment ([Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/)) not to use the full framebuffer? Their [docs](http://docs.xfce.org/) seem scarce. *I don't know what I'm doing, really.*

When looking at solutions for other single-board computers, the solutions I find are specific to each board (Like the Raspberry Pi having a solution specific to its Broadcom boot script). By looking for general-purpose Linux solutions, I find most people solving it from the specific graphics card drivers.

It's simple to describe: *I just don't want the whole screen to be used*. But I have no idea where to look.

---

[Paste with `dmesg`](http://termbin.com/5xqr).

`fbset` looks like this:

```
mode "720x480"
    geometry 720 480 720 480 16
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 5/11,6/5,5/0,0/24
endmode
```

I've tried adjusting the timings (e.g., `fbset -left N`), but even if it did report the change (by calling `fbset` again), nothing changed - changing e.g., `-xres`, on the other hand, caused visible results (screen clipping).

The display module is `tv`. `modinfo tv` gives me:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.4.112-sun8i/kernel/drivers/video/sunxi/disp2/tv/tv.ko
alias:          platform:tv
license:        GPL
description:    tv driver
author:         zengqi
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.4.112-sun8i SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
```

Comment: I don't think trying a smaller virtual size (fb or X) than screen size will work, and I also don't think xfvwm4 can restrict window placement to a smaller area. If your hardware supports it (what driver is used for composite mode? `dmesg`?) you can try to fiddle with the display timings (`fbset`) for a TV-compatible modeline with larger borders and less resolution. But there may be hardware restrictions on what modelines work. Any links to hardware documentation of the TV output part?

Comment: I've edited the question with more info (if that was not it please say) - also, do you mean this can't be done outside of the module that drives the display? (I thought `X` could clip the screen or something).

Comment: Both X and fb can use a *larger* "virtual" framebuffer, and then display *parts* of that on the various "heads" (displays), but the problem is that you need it the other way around: A smaller virtual buffer than what is displayed, and I don't think that will work, because normally the virtual framebuffer defaults to the maximum of all display extents.

Comment: TV kernel source seems to be [here](https://github.com/allwinner-zh/linux-3.4-sunxi/tree/master/drivers/video/sunxi/disp2/tv) All of `drv_tv.c`, `tv_ac200.c` and `de_tve.c` seem to use hardcoded timings (from a quick look). So, not unexpectedly, to change the TV modeline you very likely must change the source code (and try to find some hardware docs before you do that). I'm afraid I can't think of an easier way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, I wouldn't know where to look. I now see why the framebuffer should be set to the full screen, but X is drawing to the framebuffer, right? Isn't this process configurable? (Isn't this how desktop compositing such as Compiz work?)

Comment: Yes, X is drawing to the framebuffer. In principle, the window manager (xfvwm4 for Xfce) controls window placement and sizing, and should be able to restrict that so windows can only be in a certain area, but I don't know of any window manager that can be configured to enforce that. Again, you'd probably have to modify the source of one.

Comment: @dirkt I'll keep trying to find ways around hardcoding values in the video driver, but thanks to you I now know what to fall back to, that's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these commands:

```
devmem2 0x01E00130 w 0xF0050398
devmem2 0x01E00130 w 0x30050398
fbset -xres 670 -vxres 670
```

xresolution is reduced to 670, but everything is OK for my Orange Pi Zero. Maybe change to correct address of "TV ENCODER RE-SYNC PARAMETERS REGISTER (Offset 0x130)" for your SoC.

Comment: Ok it's been a month and I've been meaning to try it but have to comment I really didn't yet, I just appreciate a lot that you've added a possible solution to this problem. Given the 2 upvotes I believe someone had tried it, so now it's three :) if someone can comment confirming it works for them before I get around to it I'll accept your answer. It's really above what I would have been able to come up with on my own, I didn't even knew you could do that `devmem2` stuff from userland.